# Selenium JavaScript Try Catch block is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am trying to throw an error on the console if the first link of bing search results is clicked. My code is working fine until the first link is opened, but I am not seeing any message on the console that first link is successfully clicked and when I make an intentional code change to catch error, catch is not throwing error. I am using node.js, selenium and edge webdriver. Please help me fix this.

```
const { Builder, By } = require('selenium-webdriver');
async function launchEdgeBing() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('MicrosoftEdge').build();

  await driver.get('https://bing.com');
  await driver.manage().window().maximize();

  const element = await driver.findElement(By.id('sb_form_q'));
  await driver.sleep(5000);
  await element.sendKeys('latest news');
  await element.submit();
  await driver.sleep(5000);
  try {
    const clickFirstResult = await driver.findElement(
      
      By.className('b_title')
    );
    clickFirstResult.click();
    await driver.sleep(5000);
   
    var title = await driver.getTitle();
    console.log('Title is:', title);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e == null) {
      console.log('First link opened successfully');
    } else {
      console.log('Error is:', e);
    }
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
}
launchEdgeBing();
```

Comment: Why do you expect an error if the code runs successfully?

Comment: I want to print a message on console that if there is no error then it should print link is opened successfully.  when the test case goes into production and if for any reason we see an error, the error should also be displayed. Not sure, if I am missing anything. May be since try block is running fine, that is why it is not going to catch block? Even when there is an error in the try block, catch is not catching the error.

Comment: The `catch` block is executed only if there is an exception in the `try` block. If you move the `console.log` to the end of the `try` it will print to the console only when there are no exceptions.